# Delete a file in a specified directory C

Tags: c, file-io, directory

I believe there is a function in stdio.h called `remove()` that removes a file by passing in the file name like `remove("foo.txt")`. 
However, if I want to remove a file in a specified path, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the absolute path:

```
remove("/path/to/foo.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can do this -

remove("drive\\folder\\foo.txt"):
```

Remember you have to put `\\` between path.  `\` won't work compiler will show error.

Answer (score 1):

first check your program user rights allow to remove this file

second get full path like: `remove("/home/test/foo.txt")`